# Ubuntu 21.10 installer does not see HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an acer aspire 3. I boot the installer from a USB drive and things go fine until I need to make a new partition for Ubuntu. Here it seems like the installer can't detect the hard drive and the only available drive is the USB stick. See image [image: What I see on the installer]

This is what it looks like in GParted

[image: What it looks like on GParted. No device other than the USB stick is found.]

After some googling I found that I had to change the [SATA mode to AHCI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350) from the BIOS setup. I did this but it doesn't seem to have helped. I see that [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214795/hard-drive-not-visible-to-ubuntu-installer) describes almost exactly the same problem except with an earlier version of Ubuntu, but the question there has not been answered. Any ideas here?

Comment: According to this https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/978937/#Comment_978937 and this https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209419 it's a kernel bug (or more likely a HW bug the kernel has yet to workaround)

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest available? Amd of SSD update SSD firmware? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown
Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702
Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI

Comment: Have you tried clicking the dropdown menu in the top right corner, where your current drive is showing?